Why does python produce different result when writing code in interpreter?
I was wondering about how python stores variables in the memory. When I was playing with id() and is I found something that I was not expecting. I assume that python has something like an integer pool where an int is created and then may be referenced by variables. I also searched for it and I found an answer that there is range of values that can be stored in this pool (from -5 and 256, if I remember correctly). I was testing it in the interpreter and that actually turned out to be true. But then I wrote the same code in main.py and got different results. I am confused. How does python actually store variables?
When I try to run this code from a file with terminal, like using a command python3 main.py, the result is True.
a = 300
b = 300

print(a is b)

But when I go into python interpreter using command python3 and write the code there, the result is False.
>>> a = 300
>>> b = 300
>>> a is b
False


Basically the implementation is free to handle it one way or another. If the byte code compiler has a whole module script (non-interactive) it is probably easier to remember and process all literals at once than when they are coming in line by line in interactive mode.

Strictly speaking, Python doesn't store variables in memory, because variables are not objects. Python's data model defines mappings from names to objects; a and b are names, and 300 is a literal that evaluates to an object. The implementation-specific issue is whether each use of the literal 300 produces a reference to the same object or two distinct (but equal) objects for assignments to a and b, respectively. (1/2)

The distinction between a script (which is compiled as a unit) and the interactive interpreter (which compiles each statement separately) is that the interactive interpreter, when executing b = 300, doesn't bother looking to see of 300 has already been used; the compiler can for the script. (2/2)

If you run your example with python3 -B main.py you may find that the result is different. Python produces an intermediate bytecode version of your code that may cache literals, making both 300 be in fact the same value in memory. All of that is highly dependant on your version of the interpreter and it is generally not a good idea to rely on that for numbers.
